# Entity Framework Core 7.0 : recursive relational data not populating into second entity

Tags: .net, entity-framework-core

```
public class GUPerson : BaseEntity
{
    public int GUId { get; set; }
    public int? BasePId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public BaseP? BaseP { get; set; }
}

public class BaseP : BaseEntity
{
   public int BasePId { get; set; }
   public string? Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have two entities similar to this.

My problem is, in such a scenario

1. In GUPerson BasePId = 1, BaseP is ok
2. In GUPerson BasePId = 2, BaseP is ok
3. In GUPerson BasePId = 1, BaseP null

Why doesn't it fill the same sub-entity in another entity in the same list?

Comment: You will need to expand your answer to show how this data is being read or populated. I don't see any recursive references in this example.